# Jquery Validation Engine displaying errors in alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

In validation engine I am attempting to get the errors to display inside of a javascript alert box instead of in a small tooltip next to them.

```
$("#main_form").bind("jqv.form.result", function(event, errorFound) {
    if(errorFound)
        alert("There is a problem with your form.\n\nPlease fill out all of the required fields.");
});
```

This is currently working to display that there is an error, but I'm trying to see if there's a way to list out the fields that have errors.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of jQuery validation are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [this](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoHooks.html) plugin.

This should do the trick for you:

```
var errors = []; // initialize the error array

$('.formError').next().each(function(){ 
   errors.push($(this).attr('id'));
});

console.log(errors); //Should give you an array of elements with errors.
```